# nav and logo issue when screen resolution is less than common size

Tags: html, css

I have a header like:

```
<header id="wrapper">
    <div class="container clearfix">
    <h1 id="logo" class="alignleft"> <a href="index.html">logo</a> </h1>
    <nav class="alignright">
      <ul id="nav">

       <li><a href="#">menu 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">menu 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">menu 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">menu 4</a></li>

      </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
</header>
```

And a nav in css definition

```
ul#nav {
margin-top: 30px; 
margin-right: 50px;
}



ul#nav li { float:left; }
ul#nav li a { 
color:#9a9a9a; 
font-family: "champagne__limousinesbold", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
font-size:18px; 
font-weight:600; 
text-decoration:none; 
 margin:0px 0px 0px 15px; 
 display:inline-block; -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease 0s; -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease 0s; -o-transition: all 0.2s ease 0s; transition: all 0.2s ease 0s; padding:5px 10px; }
ul#nav li a:hover, ul#nav li a.active { color:#474747;}
ul#nav li.active a { color:#fff; background:#474747; }
```

So it works fine when the screen size is reasonable big so:

[image]

But if screen is small this happens:

[image]

Is there a way to minimize both logo (make smaller) and nav menu (make font small or something) so this does not happen?

Please take a look at [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NUgEf/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To work with responsive design, two main techniques come into play: **Percents**, **Floats**, and **Position: Relative**.  I have edited your fiddle to reflect these changes.  Notable, I added `%` margins/padding on your elements instead of pxs, adjusted the image container to have `%` dimensions, and adjusted some css on your lists.  You can see the results here:
http://jsfiddle.net/NUgEf/5/

Answer (score 0):

In a word, yes. You will want to use a media query to adjust your CSS based on the screen size.

For example:

```
@media screen and (max-width : 600px) {
    #logo {
        width: /* New width */
    }

    ul#nav li a {
        font-size: /* New font size */
    }
}
```

More on media queries [here](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries)

Comment: Media queries are supported in IE9+. That said, most IE8- browser windows are at least 960px wide.

Answer (score 0):

It kind of depends on what you want the menu to do when there's not enough room for it. You could force the links to start wrapping onto separate lines on small screens without using @media rules with some changes like this:

```
h1#logo {
float: left;
margin-left: 10px;
margin-top: 0px;
}
h1#logo a { 
display:block; 
width:239px; 
height:147px; 
text-indent:-9999px; 
text-decoration:none; 
background:url(http://blog.logobee.com/free-logo1.jpg) left top no-repeat;
}

nav.alignright {display: block; overflow: hidden;}

.alignright {
/* float: right; */  /* remove this */
}
```

Here's a live demo: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/miFyx